# Can anyone tell me where can i publish or host my chrome extension code for all?

Tags: git, google-chrome-extension, hosting

Is there a option available to upload google chrome extension. I dont want to use google app store, as for now i dont want to pay $5 so.
I want this extension to be downloadble by all for free. So what are the steps and requirements to upload chrome extension elsewhere. 
I know about git but not sure whether chrome extensions can be uploaded there? iF yes i would like to know how??

Answer (score 0):

Create a self-hosted web page for your extension or create a google-code page for your extension. If it is something that you expect to get a lot of users, I would recommend going for the $5 option as you will see many more users.